# How to handle "Expected member name or constructor call after type name" error introduced after Swift3 upgrade

Tags: swift3

After going through the upgrade to Swift3, the upgrade helper changed

```
private var myArray = [(String, NSDate, Float)]() //Swift 2.2
```

to

```
fileprivate var myArray = [(String, Foundation.Date, Float)] //Swift 3
```

The new code gives an error `Expected member name or constructor call after type name`.

Does anyone understand the reason for the error or what the correct syntax approach should be?  The proposed solutions from the compiler are to `Add arguments after the type to construct a value of the type` or `Use .self to reference the type object`.  These don't fix the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You simply need to initialize the array by adding the `()` at the end.

```
fileprivate var myArray = [(String, Date, Float)]()
```

Comment: superb! problem solved.. what's strange is I had those parenthesis in there before

Answer (score 3):

If adding `()` at the end doesn't help, try with `.self` instead:

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
```